# XML php for google maps: error on line .. at column ..: EntityRef: expecting ';'

Tags: php, xml, google-maps, entityreference

I used to have a good working XML file on my site (source for a google map). Until a few days ago got this error:

**This page contains the following errors:
error on line 2 at column 10896: EntityRef: expecting ';'
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.**

I have not made changes to the php file in that time period. Also did some database checks, all seems to be in order (the database connection is working fine).

I read that a common cause for this is using *&* instead of *&amp*. But in the `parseToXML` there is a replace function for that, so that couldn't be the cause I was thinking.

Any tips?

Thank you!

Mark

```
require("credentials.php");

function parseToXML($htmlStr)
{
    $xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr);
    $xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr);
    $xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr);
    $xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr);
    $xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);
    return $xmlStr;
}

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, name, address, lat, lng, descrip FROM people";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';
$ind=0;
// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     // Add to XML document node
     echo '<marker ';
     echo 'id="' . $row['id'] . '" ';
     echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
     echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
     echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
     echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
     echo 'descrip="' . $row['descrip'] . '" ';
     echo '/>';
     $ind = $ind + 1;
 }

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';
```

Comment: I would recommend using a proper api to generate the XML, they understand more of the limitations of XML and stand a better chance of encoding the data properly than you may be able to put in.

Comment: yep that's why it's wonky when you create an xml by hand, better off to use `DOMDocument` or `SimpleXML`, but in any case, (maybe) there's something wrong with the description breaking off the markup

Comment: You are applying your `parseToXML` function (`htmlspecialchars` exists, btw.) to the `name` and `address` fields only, but not to `descrip` … I don’t know what kind of data you are having there, but that a description field might occasionally contain ampersands, doesn’t sound so far fetched maybe …

Answer (score 0):

Rather than manually writing out a string it is far easier and more reliable to generate your XML using the various tools designed for the job. PHP has the `DOMDocument` class which makes tasks like this very straightforward and requires fewer lines of code too ;-/
It also has the benefit of not stuttering if the text content contains chevrons or other characters

```
<?php
    require 'credentials.php';
    $conn = new mysqli( $servername, $username, $password, $dbname );

    $sql = 'select id, name, address, lat, lng, descrip from people';
    $result = $conn->query( $sql );
    
    
    # generate new DOMDocument & set properties
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    $dom->xmlStandalone = true;
    
    # create the root node and add to the DOM
    $root=$dom->createElement('markers');
    $dom->appendChild( $root ); 
    
    # for convenience it is quicker to iterate through this array to generate attributes
    # thse correspond to the column names / aliases from the sql query
    $attribs=[ 'id', 'name', 'address', 'lat', 'lng', 'descrip' ];
    
    # iterate through recordset, generate new node for each record
    while( $row = $result->fetch_object() ) {
        #add the new node to DOM
        $marker=$dom->createElement('marker');
        $root->appendChild( $marker );
        
        #add attributes
        foreach( $attribs as $attr ){
            $marker->setAttribute( $attr, $row->$attr );
        }
    }
    
    #save or echo?
    header('Content-Type: text/xml');
    echo $dom->saveXML();
    
    #$dom->save('/path/to/file.xml');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

@CBroe @Kevin, wow great that you spotted this. Indeed found out in the last few days, an entry in the database was made. An user added that day a text in the `descrip` field, that contained the & symbol. That killed the XML file output. I now applied `parseToXML` as well to that `descrip` line and that fixed the problem.

@Nigel Ren and all, would agree that what I am using now is a bit wonky. Open and honoust, would describe my entire website setup as "wonky" :-). Will look into your suggestions though, for further improvements. For now, thanks so much all!